# Getting iPhone bluetooth to pair with a raspberry pi to serve as 4G hotspot

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, raspbian-buster, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I'm trying to figure out a way to pair an iPhone to a Raspberry Pi 4 (with a PIN ideally, but without is okay). Once paired, I'm going to set up the iPhone as a hotspot. All user interaction has to be **from the iPhone** since the Pi will be headless later on (plus other reasons).

There's lots of info I've learned that has been helpful but hasn't solved this:

- Pairing to an RPi classic BT (not BLE) works fine with non-Apple devices (Windows, Android)
- I can get an iPhone to pair with a BCM2046B1 dongle on Windows 10 using Bluecove 2.1.1.

  - The same dongle does not work on Raspbian using bluetoothctl.
- I cant rely on easier pairing that you get with BLE (unless tethering works with BLE)
- I cant rely on easier pairing with being an audio device (since this is for tethering, not audio)
- Someone in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38508/bluetooth-connection-with-iphone) suggests the BT device needs to be MFI certified to work

Any tips / info is appreciated, even if not a complete answer.  Just knowing more about Apple's secret sauce for BT pairing would be helpful.  Seems most people have given up when trying this, but might be easier with Pi4 / PiOS Buster.

Comment: By default there is no [Network Aggregation Point](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/network-api.txt) [nap] running on the Raspberry Pi. You would need to set that up on your RPi to tether to it from the iPhone. This can be a little tricky to get setup. What I know is documented at:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114551/121848

Comment: Thank you, @ukBaz. Looks a bit complicated from a glance.  Was hoping for something more plug-and-play but seems not.